# Xcode 5 textview hyperlink not active

Tags: url, hyperlink, textview, xcode5

I transitioned my iphone app project into Xcode 5 so it has taken on the new look. I have found that a textview containing only a URL hyperlink that previously worked fine in Xcode 4 now does not show an active link. If I touch the link text and hold, I get the "Copy/Define" functionality from the iPhone and then the link becomes active and turns blue. I have Text View Detection Links checked. Not sure why the link does not show as active all the time.

Comment: I have found that if I load enough additional text along with the hyperlink text in the textview so that the text renders on more that one line, the hyperlink comes alive. Not sure if this is an Xcode 5 thing or iOS 7 thing.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I recommend reporting it to apple via bugreport.apple.com.